# using raster::getValues() to get values for a partial image

Tags: r, raster

I am using `raster` as shown below. The last line provides values for the entire image. How should I modify my command to get values for just part of the image, i.e. `xlim=c(0, 299)`, `ylim=c(0, 199)`?

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
f <- "pictures/image1-1421787394.jpeg"
f
r <- raster(f)
plot(r);
r
plot(r,xlim=c(0,299),ylim=c(0,199))
getValues(r)
```

I also wanted to add a circular extent and the second answer has showed how to do it.

Comment: You can use `extract` function together with an `extent` object. Or first `crop` your Raster* object.

Comment: Please don't include irrelevant code in posts to SO. We don't have your file, so the assignment to `f` is not useful, nor are the `plot` calls or the printing of `f` and `r`. (In general, these might prove useful if you actually include the _output_ of the calls as well.) Best of all is to include a self contained, simple example that we can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, which keeps track of cell coordinates:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))
e <- extent(0.2, 0.45, 0.1, 0.68)

plot(r)
plot(e, add=TRUE, lwd=2)
```

[image]

```
cbind(xyFromCell(r, cellsFromExtent(r, e)),
      z=extract(r, cellsFromExtent(r, e)))      

#         x    y         z
# [1,] 0.25 0.65 0.9605758
# [2,] 0.35 0.65 0.9654382
# [3,] 0.25 0.55 0.6888101
# [4,] 0.35 0.55 0.1091108
# [5,] 0.25 0.45 0.7774158
# [6,] 0.35 0.45 0.1773767
# [7,] 0.25 0.35 0.2323325
# [8,] 0.35 0.35 0.2982672
# [9,] 0.25 0.25 0.0191205
# [10,] 0.35 0.25 0.5675381
# [11,] 0.25 0.15 0.9414032
# [12,] 0.35 0.15 0.7272289
```

Cells with centres that fall within the extent, or with centres that fall exactly on the left or lower boundary of the extent, will be included. Note that despite the extent having `xmax` of 0.45, the cells in column 5 are not included.

Comment: Is there a way to draw an extent which is of circular shape? My actual objects are circular and it will be much better if i apply extent function inside that circle only..thanks

Comment: lets say I want  a circle that is centered at 0.4,0.4 in the above image and it's radius in 0.3

Answer (score 2):

Simplifying jbaums code:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(1)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))
e <- extent(0.2, 0.45, 0.1, 0.68)
extract(r, e)
```

user2543622 changed the question to wanting "a circle that is centered at 0.4,0.4 in the above image and it's radius in 0.3". You can create a SpatialPolygon and extract with that.

```
library(dismo)
cr <- circles(cbind(0.4, 0.4), d=0.3, lonlat=F)
p <- polygons(cr)
plot(r)
plot(p, add=TRUE)
extract(r, p)
```

Comment: This simplification is sensible, but note that it doesn't return the cell coordinates corresponding to the extracted values (it'd be nice to see this implemented in a future release, e.g. via a `spatial` arg).